# Laravel Backpack Crud Search encrypted data fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a encrypted user table and need to find a solution for search from encrypted data fields using Laravel Backpack crud 4.1.

How do we filter data from encrypted fields?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anybody stumbling upon this, I believe the best option would be to [define a custom searchLogic](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#custom-search-logic-for-columns) for each encrypted column you have. That way you take full control of how search is done for that column.

Alternatively you can [overwrite the search()](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-list-entries#the-search-logic) method of the ListOperation, but that’s more invasive and I don’t think it’s necessary.